# php binding textbox value after submit button onclick

Tags: php, ajax

I want to submit the textbox value and bind the value in the textbox after the submit button onclick.

```
echo '<td>';
echo '<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">';
echo Enter here:<br><input type="text" id="textbox1" name="tb1" value="" size="3"<br/>
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnenter'" value="Enter" />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</td>';

if ( isset( $_POST[btnenter] ) ) {
            $value1 = $_POST[tb1]; 
}
```

I can get the value, but how to bind the value?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="tb1" value="" size="3"<br/>
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="tb1" value=". $value ." size="3"<br/>
```

Also it would work even if you dont check if the valuable exists, since it would be null so you may prefer not to check if "isnull".

also when using echo, if you use double quotes ("), you can use variables in your echo. such as:

```
 <input type='text' id='textbox1' name='tb1' value='${value}' size='3'<br/>
```

Comment: yes, if ( isset( $_POST[btnenter] ) ) {
            $value1 = $_POST[tb1]; 
} you could move this to top.

Answer (score 1):

```
$value1 = "";

if ( isset( $_POST[btnenter] ) ) {
    if( isset( $_POST[tb1] ) ){
        $value1 = $_POST[tb1]; 
    }
}

echo '<td>';
echo '<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">';
echo Enter here:<br><input type="text" id="textbox1" name="tb1" value=". $value1 ." size="3"<br/>
<input type="submit" id="btn1" name = "btnenter'" value="Enter" />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</td>';
```

Comment: @user3118482 +1 to you for being so polite